# When the "while loop" is over, it writes "aaa" twice

Tags: python, while-loop, printing

Code:

```
n = 10
def test():
    global n
    
    while n > 0:
        n -= 1
        print(n)
        if n == 2:
            test()
    print("aaa")

test()
```

Output:

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
aaa
aaa
```

Why does it write "aaa" twice?

I need to use it in my another project but it writes it twice.

Comment: Its because you call `test()` twice. I'm curious, why do you do that?

Comment: Why the recursive call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call test() in the if statement, that causes the function to print out the rest of the numbers and then "aaa".

Once it has done that, the program returns to the point at which test() was last called (in the if statement) so it carries on running and prints "aaa" again.

Comment: okay I get it now. but is there a way to not write it twice because when I do this on my other code, it writes the result twice.

Comment: Just delete the lines: `if n == 2: test()` and it'll work fine.

Comment: You could either not call test() in the if statement or move the print statement to after the original function call outside of the test() function

Answer (score 0):

You call test() which prints "aaa" at the end.
Test also calls itself when n==2 and prints "aaa" at the end before returning to the test() that called it.

Answer (score 0):

First "aaa" is printed because of test() called in "if n == 2" condition and 2nd "aaa" is printed just before test function ends. And since n is global its value is not initialized in second call and it continues from previous value.